# Compounded SUM in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get compounded sum in sql server? e.g.

**Month  Salary Total**

**Jan**    1000   1000

**Feb**    1200   2200

**Mar**    1000   3200

. . .

. . .

Please help.

Comment: which version of sql server

Comment: What have you tried? If you have anything lower than SQL 2012 this might be a good place to start. http://www.pawlowski.cz/2010/09/sql-server-and-fastest-running-totals-using-clr/

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi It doesnot have any identity column

Comment: then how'd you define a primary key on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @t table( Months varchar(10), Salary int) 
insert into @t
select 'Jan', 1000 union all
select 'Feb', 1200 union all
select 'Mar', 1000
;With CTE as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))rn from @t
)
,CTE1 as
(
select a.*,salary [Total] from CTE a where rn=1
union all
select a.*,a.Salary+Total from CTE a inner join CTE1 b on a.rn-b.rn=1
)
select * from cte1
```

Answer (score 2):

if the table structure's like this `table(id int identity(1,1),month varchar(10),salary int,total int)`

then you could try :

```
select *,(select sum(salary) 
          from table b  
          where b.id<=a.id) as total 
from table a
```

## <kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15698)</kbd>